# Convert inches to metric in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

in my table, I have string values like `3/4"`, `1"`, `1 1/8"` etc, and I need to convert those to metric. The straightforward (and ugly) way would be to do multistep conversion to a number (1. Find the position of the space character; 2. Take the left part before space and keep it as integer; 3. Find the position of slash character; 4. Divide the before-slash part to after-slash part) and only then I can use something like `=CONVERT(G1,"in","mm")`. Is there any better solution? For example, if I just query google with [1 1/8" to mm](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%201%2F8%22%20to%20mm), I will get what I need right away - is there way to perform this query for spreadsheet values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution I found so far is to write my custom function:

```
function replInches(str1){
  return(eval(str1.replace("\"","").replace(" ","+")));
}
```

and then call it like `=CONVERT(replInches(A2),"in","mm")`

Answer (score 0):

Select cells to suit, Edit > Find and Replace ..., Find [space] / Replace with `+` then an Edit > Find and Replace.., Find of:

```
(.+)"
```

/ Replace with:

```
=25.4*($1)
```

selecting Search using regular expressions works for the examples provided.

Comment: not sure I understand correctly... I tried, as you suggest, to replace space by `+` and remove `"`: `=REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","+"),"(.+)"&CHAR(34),"$1")` - but the result is still a string which can't be correctly converted to a number: in case of `3/4`, it will be interpreted as a date, and in case of `1+1/8` it will just give an error...

Comment: ah, now I see, thanks! I wanted to use only the functions and avoid "manual" replacement.